# Make excel like interface for android app

Tags: java, android, gridview, tableview

The question is how to make excel like interface for table with possibility of text modification.

Now i have parsed excel file to strings array and passed it to GridView structure.

```
 GridView gvMain;
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
 adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);
 gvMain = new GridView(this);
 gvMain.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Basically, this construction doesn't allow me to modify text in the cells. What i want to achieve is a EditText like behaviour for each cell (or you can say excel like behaviour when you can click on the cell and type what ever you want). As i understand for achieving this i must somehow override Adapter's getView method (?). Is it possible or i'am using unappropriate API (GridView)? Actually, i have tried with TableView, but i mentioned that for some reason this stuff works very slow (i have big excel file).

Can you help me to choose an appropiate way for solving this task? Thanks!

Comment: If there is some problem with this question you can leave a comment

Comment: Have you find a solution on this?

Comment: @Karyuu Ouji yes, i will give you link to the sources tomorrow

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2fQg5hYfFP7UHc2QjZkVTB4cFE